# Filter in tableau to hide some values

Tags: tableau-api

I want to show sales against regions and want to exclude North America and South America from both filter and in the visualisation.

[image]

What i did is put Mega region in filter,
select all from list,
unchecked these two region
click OK.
With these approach I am able to exclude them from the visualisation but still they are there in the filter. Also when ALL is selected they all comes in.

[image]

I want to exclude them from filters as well. Filter will be single value drop down and when "All" is selected then Asia, Australia and Europe should come. Can someone please suggest?
Below is the screen shot of the dummy data.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the filter to your worksheet selecting the **Mega Region** values you want (already done)

Then, duplicate your Mega Region field and put the **Mega Region Copy** field into the filter pane and select all values.

Right click Mega Region Copy --> Show Filter

Once the filter is visible in your worksheet/dashboard, click on the upper right corner of the filter and select "Only Relevant Values".

Doing so, you're just showing values satisfying previously applied conditions.

Comment: @ Fabio- Is there any way to hide those two in filter also?

Comment: could you please add more context? I'm not getting your point, probably.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Filter these out as a data source filter
2. Duplicate the "Mega Region" field, place the duplicate on the filter shelf and add to context, removing the Americas. Also put the original on the filter shelf but set it to only show values in context.